# Como no ASP.NET 5 essa propriedade é definida?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, propriedade

No ASP.NET 5 no método `Configure` da classe `Startup` podemos receber nos parametros uma referencia a um objeto cuja classe implemente `IHostingEnvironment`. Uma das propriedades dessa classe é `EnvironmentName`. Já vi em códigos de exemplo uma realização de uma verificação nessa propriedade para detalhar erros ou não. Se essa propriedade for `Development` então trata-se do ambiente de desenvolvimento e mostra-se os erros em detalhes. Caso contrário trata-se do ambiente de produção e mostra-se uma página amigavel avisando que ocorreu um erro.

Até aí tudo bem, o que eu não entendo é como essa propriedade é definida. Por que sempre que rodo ela tem valor "Development"? Como essa propriedade é realmente definida?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você está procurando está no código de [`ConfigureHostingEnvironment.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/217f9ca3d3ccf59ea06e6555820974ba9c3b5932/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/ConfigureHostingEnvironment.cs):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;

namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting
{
    internal class ConfigureHostingEnvironment : IConfigureHostingEnvironment
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        private const string EnvironmentKey = "ASPNET_ENV"; //esta é a variável de ambiente

        public ConfigureHostingEnvironment(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public void Configure(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv)
        {
            hostingEnv.EnvironmentName = _config.Get(EnvironmentKey) ?? hostingEnv.EnvironmentName;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/Config.cs).

Então para mudar a propriedade é necessário alterar a variável de ambiente `ASPNET_ENV` no sistema operacional.

Há uma [discussão sobre isto no GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/139).

Answer (score 0):

O que o @Maniero disse em [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51810/2998) está correto! E aquele é processo interno que é utilizado para obter o valor de `EnvironmentName`.

Mas para testar seu sistema em outro ambiente em tempo de desenvolvimento você não necessariamente deve ter que setar a variável de ambiente do OS, a ferramenta Visual Studio já disponibiliza uma forma de você configurar/alterar variáveis de ambiente para o seu projeto, que é a seguinte:

Clique com o botão direito sobre seu projeto e depois em `Properties`, irá surgir o painel de propriedades de seu projeto, acesse a sessão/tab `Debug` e em seguinda você vai observar uma tabela de propriedades chamada "Environment Variables", que seriam as variáveis de ambiente para o projeto, seria algum similar a isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então para testar você pode alterar o valor da propriedade `Hosting:Environment` para `Production`, assim ao rodar o sistema novamente o valor da propriedade `EnvironmentName` do objeto `IHostingEnvironment` será "Production".